# How to apply CORS header in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add layers to my google Maps using files hosted in other domains.

I searched about it and I figured out that I need to add the following code in my HTML.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

But how to do that? I tried in different ways but didn't work.
Someone could show me the trick to get it working?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map_canvas {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: -18.92990560776172,
        lng: -43.4406814550781
      }
    });


    var Cities = new google.maps.Data();
    Cities.loadGeoJson('http://nucleotravessia.unifei.edu.br/MapaTravessia/Files_LoadMap/Limites_Muni.geojson');
    Cities.setStyle({
      strokeColor: '#058E8E',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
    });
    Cities.setMap(map);

  }
</script>


<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&v=3.24&key=AIzaSyBFYwb6-B6u2cs5oknTRwtfBng2kgdDMgk&libraries=drawing,geometry&language=pt-BR&region=BR&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Setting that header? That header is supposed to be for the site you are requesting, not on the page that you are making the call from. That site that is giving you the json is supposed to set it. You can not alter it from your end.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working recently, here's the snipit:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(...);
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");    
...
request.send(...);
```